# How to take screenshot of test stpes in ready API? Do we need to take screenshot of test cases?

Tags: ready-api

-Test suite
-Test steps
-Test case execution
-Apply assertion
-generate report

> Do we take screenshot of test cases in ReadyApi?

Comment: Please reply soon, I have an interview tomorrow.

Comment: why do you want to take screenshot of test steps ? its API testing, not UI testing. Maybe you describe your question first.